# Linksys wifi router performs 50% of wired connection

Tags: ethernet, ieee-802.11

So, I have switched to a gigabit internet connection at my house.  Through the internet provider's modem, I consistently get between 800-950 Mbps when I check.  But, through the wifi on the internet provider's modem, I get around 300-350 Mbps.  So, I got out my relatively new router that I thought I bought to do gigabit speeds and it still pumps out 300-350 Mbps.  So, I was in Best Buy and was talking to a guy there and he said I just needed a better router.  I got a new linksys router (MAX-STREAM AC5000) with three bands.  The 5G band I think is rated at 2166 Mbps.  Anyways, I plugged it up and now get around 500-550 with my computer plugged up a foot away.  I was going to move my computer back to where it was in the other room to see if it goes back down to 350, but 500-550 is still not even close to the speed of my wired connection..

Am I just dreaming in this day and age to get a gigabit wifi connection?!?  Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Sadly, home networking is off topic here.  You can ask these questions on SuperUser.com.  But briefly, your throughput depends primarily on three things:  The capability of the access point/modem, the distance from the access point, and the capability of your computer/mobile device.  The last one seems to be a constant.  Your computer may not have enough antennas/streams to go faster than 500 Mbps.

Comment: Ok.  I can ask it there.  I keep getting all my stack exchange sites mixed up haha.  Just a quick response, I have a 5k iMac that is only around a year or two old.  I would think it is new enough to handle gigabit speeds through wifi?  I guess I never thought about that.. my iPhone only does 350 with it being 1 foot away and my iMac does 550.

Comment: No Wi-Fi client can do gigabit on Wi-Fi. You would need MIMO with four antennae. The entire WAP can possibly do over 1 Gbps, but not with a single client.

Comment: Actually, there's one (but only one for now), in the presence of the Asus PCE-AC88. It's a 4x4 11ac STA that atteigns the practical gigabit speeds in a faraday cage (read 900-950Mbps). It embarks a Broadcom 4366. It can also probably do better in a Broadcom only environment, using 1024-QAM.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that your WiFi card on your laptop will only support speeds of 300-350 Mbps -- that sounds a lot like the high practical end on most mainstream WiFi adapters.

Keep in mind that WiFi has a lot more variables that Wired Ethernet -- so "Practical" speed is often different that "Theoretical Max" speeds.

Comment: I am using an iMac to do my testing with.  Is there a way for me to check my wireless card's max speed?  My iPhone taps out at 350 it seems which would be in line with what you are saying.

Comment: You'd need to know the model of the iMac and the model of the Wireless Adapter.  Look up their specs to see what version of WiFi they max out at (N, AC, etc) and their Theoretical Max.  Again, keep in mind that Practical Max will be lower.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to look that up now.  It's a mid 2015.  I am pretty sure it is ac, but let me check

Comment: You can check in the system informations, but that's probably some Broadcom chipset.